# OpenAI API answer from the server

Tags: javascript, axios, xmlhttprequest, openai-api

I am making a chatbot and I have a problem to get answer from the server. In console I get a message that request failed with status 401. I really can´t find out where I made a mistake. I think that the problem can be with Api key, should I not import it from the env? I really don´t know how to fix it

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';



const Chatbot = () => {
    const [typing, setTyping] = useState(false);
    const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
        {
            message: "Hello, I'm ChatGPT! Ask me anything!",
            sender: "ChatGPT",
        },
    ]);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

        const sendMessage = async () => {
            if (input.trim() === "") {
                return;
            }


        setMessages((prevMessages)  => [
            ...prevMessages,
            {
                message: input,
                sender: "User"
            }
            ]);
        setInput("");

        try {
            setTyping(true);
            const response = await
            axios.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", 
            {
                prompt: `User: ${input}\nChatGPT:`,
                max_tokens: 150,
            },
            {
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages: [
                    {
                        role: "system",
                        content: input
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer $API_KEY'
                },       
            }
            );
            console.log('OpenAI response:', response.data);
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [ 
            ...prevMessages, 
            {
                message: response.data.choice[0].message.content,
                sender: "Chat GPT" 
            }
        ]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        } finally {
            setTyping(false);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div style={ChatbotStyles.chatbot}>
            <div style={ChatbotStyles.chatbox}>
                <div style={ChatbotStyles.info}>
                    {messages.map((msg, index) => (
                        <div key={index} style={msg.sender === "Chat GPT" ? ChatbotStyles.chatGPTMessage : ChatbotStyles.userMessage}>
                        {msg.message}
                           </div>
                    ))}
                    </div>
                    <input
                    style={ChatbotStyles.input}
                    value={input} 
                    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Type a message" />
                    <button style={ChatbotStyles.button} onClick={sendMessage} >Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
 };

 
 export default Chatbot;
```